# Is there a good client to browse and update data in Amazon SimpleDB?

Tags: simpledb

S3Fox allows you to browse your Amazon S3 files and do uploading/downloading.  Is there any similar tool for Amazon SimpleDB?  E.g. something like SQL Enterprise Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS Toolkit for Eclipse](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/) is a free tool that helps work with several Amazon services, including SimpleDB.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search returns [SimpleDB Explorer](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/), a UI which does just this. Unfortunately, it's not free (although there is a 30-day free trial).

Answer (score 1):

A free tool (Google Chrome plugin) is available at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ddhigekdfabonefhiildaiccafacphgg?hc=search&hcp=main